# Neo4j streaming in user-defined procedures

Tags: scala, neo4j

When using Neo4j unmanaged extensions, one can stream results to the client while traversing the graph like this (in Scala):

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.{MediaType, Response, StreamingOutput}

val stream: StreamingOutput = ???
Response.ok().entity(stream).`type`(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build()
```

I can't find a similar possibility when using Neo4j 3 used-defined stored procedures. They return Java 8 `Stream`s but I can't see how I could add elements to such streams while they already being consumed, in parallel.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an example of that in one of the [APOC procedures](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures).

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/master/src/main/java/apoc/cypher/Cypher.java#L77

I want to add more / a more general example of that in the future.

Comment: On the surface it looks like what I need. Would be nice to have this in docs though. Thank you for answering so fast.

Comment: Interesting that sometimes 100 ms timeout in the blocking queue is not enough (at least in tests).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with based on Michael Hunger code (in Scala).

**QueueBasedSpliterator**:

```
import java.util.Spliterator
import java.util.concurrent.{BlockingQueue, TimeUnit}
import java.util.function.Consumer

import org.neo4j.kernel.api.KernelTransaction

private class QueueBasedSpliterator[T](queue: BlockingQueue[T],
                                       tombstone: T,
                                       tx: KernelTransaction) extends Spliterator[T] {

  override def tryAdvance(action: Consumer[_ >: T]): Boolean =
    try {
      if (tx.shouldBeTerminated()) false
      else {
        val entry = queue.poll(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        if (entry == null || entry == tombstone) false
        else {
          action.accept(entry)
          true
        }
      }
    } catch {
      case e: InterruptedException => false
    }

  override def trySplit(): Spliterator[T] = null

  override def estimateSize(): Long = Long.MaxValue

  override def characteristics(): Int = Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.NONNULL

}
```

Notice the 100 ms timeout value. Might require tuning.

**ResultsStream** (wrapper around blocking queue):

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue

class ResultsStream[T](tombstone: T, queue: BlockingQueue[T]) extends AutoCloseable {

  def put(t: T): Unit = {
    queue.put(t)
  }

  override def close(): Unit = {
    put(tombstone)
  }

}
```

**CommonUtil** helper methods:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue
import java.util.stream.{Stream, StreamSupport}

import org.neo4j.kernel.api.KernelTransaction
import org.neo4j.kernel.internal.GraphDatabaseAPI

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

object CommonUtil {

  def inTx(db: GraphDatabaseAPI)(f: => Unit): Unit =
    Managed(db.beginTx()) { tx => f; tx.success() }

  def inTxFuture(db: GraphDatabaseAPI)(f: => Unit)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Unit] =
    Future(inTx(db)(f))

  def streamResults[T](tombstone: T, tx: KernelTransaction)
                      (f: ResultsStream[T] => Any): Stream[T] = {
    val queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue[T](100)
    f(new ResultsStream(tombstone, queue))
    StreamSupport.stream(new QueueBasedSpliterator[T](queue, tombstone, tx), false)
  }

}
```

Some more helpers:

```
object Managed {
  type AutoCloseableView[T] = T => AutoCloseable

  def apply[T : AutoCloseableView, V](resource: T)(op: T => V): V =
    try {
      op(resource)
    } finally {
      resource.close()
    }
}
```

**Pool**:

```
import java.util.concurrent.{ArrayBlockingQueue, ThreadPoolExecutor, TimeUnit}

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, ExecutionContextExecutor}

object Pool {

  lazy val DefaultExecutionContent: ExecutionContextExecutor =
    ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(createDefaultExecutor())

  // values might be tuned in production
  def createDefaultExecutor(corePoolSize: Int = Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors() * 2,
                            keepAliveSeconds: Int = 30) = {
    val queueSize = corePoolSize * 25

    new ThreadPoolExecutor(
      corePoolSize / 2,
      corePoolSize,
      keepAliveSeconds.toLong,
      TimeUnit.SECONDS,
      new ArrayBlockingQueue[Runnable](queueSize),
      new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy()
    )
  }

}
```

**Usage in a procedure**:

```
@Procedure("example.readStream")
def readStream(@Name("nodeId") nodeId: NodeId): Stream[StreamingItem] =
  CommonUtil.streamResults(StreamingItem.Tombstone, kernelTx) { results =>
    CommonUtil.inTxFuture(db) { // uses Pool.DefaultExecutionContent
      Managed(results) { _ =>
        graphUtil.findTreeNode(nodeId).foreach { node =>
          // add elements to the stream here
          results.put(???)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

`StreamingItem.Tombstone` is just a static `StreamingItem` instance with special meaning to close the stream. `db` and `kernelTx` are just context variable set by Neo4j:

```
  @Context
  public GraphDatabaseAPI db;

  @Context
  public KernelTransaction kernelTx;
```